# Cacti Graph - Raw value instead of average

Tags: cacti

Problem 1:

I have the custom script that output's `"processes:<value>"` and I've graph template Item #1 `Graph item type as "Line1"` and `CF Type "LAST"` but that would throw `"ERROR: the RRD does not contain an RRA matching the chosen CF"`.  So I chose CF Type "`Average"` but then when the script output is `"processes:21"` the graph shows `average "6.5x".`

I'm using `cacti 0.8.7e-3` and on their forums they are forcing us to use `"Average"` instead of `"LAST"` to get rid of `"RRD does not contain an RRA matching error"`

Problem 2:

Not that just but the units are shown as `m` which means milli. I want  to show raw value `21` and if its above `1000` then show it as `1k`.

How do I solve these 2 problems?

Answer (score 0):

Solved both the problems.

I had to set `"Data Source Type"` to `"GUAGE"` under Data Templates. Now I see raw values and removed unit `m (milli)`.